# Failed to start up socket within 45000 milliseconds. Attempted to connect to the following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running my code on server.Can anyone tell what are the possible reasons for this error apart from version compatibility.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​And...what's your code?

Comment: You probably need to update your selenium jar. Please get the latest version 2.52 from here (http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Comment: most of the time, check version of selenium jar compatibility with your firefox version.

Comment: Can the latest version 2.52 of selenium work with firefox 41.0.2 ?

Comment: Apart from version issues what could be the possible reasons for this error

Comment: 2.52 should go with FF45; if you use FF41, I think you should use selenium 2.48; part of the version compability, there should be an issue with firewall.

Comment: Actually this error is not coming all the time.

Comment: Its coming one in a day

Comment: I am running the application through task scheduler every 10 minutes

Comment: Can i use 2.51 with FF41.0.2.

Comment: Hi Nguyen Vu Hoang If the issue is with the  firewall then what is that issue